# Multiplication by broadcasting rows of 2D array to each slice of 3D array using np.einsum

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, broadcast, multiplication

I have the arrays `A` and `B`:

```py
>>> import numpy as np

>>> A = np.ones((3,3,2))

>>> B = np.array([
    [0,0],
    [1,1],
    [2,2],
])
```

I want to multiply each row of `B` to each slice of `A`, such that each row of `B` gets broadcast over each slice of `A`, that is:

```py
>>> np.array([A_slice*B_row for A_slice, B_row in zip(A, B)])
[[[0. 0.]
  [0. 0.]
  [0. 0.]]

 [[1. 1.]
  [1. 1.]
  [1. 1.]]

 [[2. 2.]
  [2. 2.]
  [2. 2.]]]
```

I want the most efficient method for doing this, which I believe may be using `np.einsum` (however if you think using another method is faster, for example the one I mention below, do tell me).

I have attempted the follwing:

```py
>>> np.einsum('ijk,lk->ijk', A, B)
[[[3. 3.]
  [3. 3.]
  [3. 3.]]

 [[3. 3.]
  [3. 3.]
  [3. 3.]]

 [[3. 3.]
  [3. 3.]
  [3. 3.]]]
```

As you can see this is clearly not the same output as above.

Another solution that I can think of is:

```py
>>> A*B[:,np.newaxis,:].repeat(3, axis=1)
[[[0. 0.]
  [0. 0.]
  [0. 0.]]

 [[1. 1.]
  [1. 1.]
  [1. 1.]]

 [[2. 2.]
  [2. 2.]
  [2. 2.]]]
```

Which does give the correct output, but I still really want to know how to do it with `np.einsum`

**EDIT:**
Warren Weckesser has pointed out in the comments that the solution above can be simplified to `A*B[:,np.newaxis,:]`, which is the cleanest solution I have seen yet without using `np.einsum`.

Comment: `B` is (4,2), `A` is (3,3,2).  What's supposed to happen with the last row of `B`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to edit it out. B should be (3,2), thanks for the heads up

Comment: You can simplify your last solution by removing the use of `repeat`: `A*B[:, np.newaxis, :] `.  What you accomplished with `repeat` is, in effect, what broadcasting does.

Comment: Very good point, I completely overlooked that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`numpy.einsum` soution:

```
C = np.einsum('ijk,jk->jik', A, B)
```

Using elipsis:

```
C = np.einsum('ij...,j...->ji...', A, B)
```

Output

```
[[[0. 0.]
  [0. 0.]
  [0. 0.]]

 [[1. 1.]
  [1. 1.]
  [1. 1.]]

 [[2. 2.]
  [2. 2.]
  [2. 2.]]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, this does indeed work for the case that I illustrated, however I tried to "expand" the problem a little:
 `A = np.ones((4,3,2))`
`B = np.array([[0,0],[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]])`
and it got an error saying `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (4,3,2)->(3,4,2) (4,2)->(4,newaxis,2)`